# Angular 2 cli with Express js

Tags: node.js, web-services, express, angular, angular-cli

I want to use express js w/ node js to be my server for an angular 2 project. I was looking at tutorials for integrating express js w/ the angular cli (I followed  [this](https://javascriptrocks.wordpress.com/2016/06/04/express-with-angular-cli-in-5-minutes/) and [this](http://tattoocoder.com/angular2-giving-your-cli-server/)) and I had no luck. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this? Currently I have a new project up w/ cli just something that says "app works!" and want to try to do it using express as opposed to using the lite server. 
any help is appreciated!

Comment: `ng build` and make `Express JS` host the `dist` directory. I'm sorry without more specific information I can't help much more than that.

Comment: i tried that it and it only shows the "loading..." thing in the index.html . does it not load other components automatically?

Comment: anything in the browser console?

Comment: ok so i get this when i use the index html from the dist folder: "inline.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < styles.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < main.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" but when i change the directory for the get request to src in express instead of dist, i get nothing on the console but it still displays "loading..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this [link](http://tattoocoder.com/angular2-giving-your-cli-server/) works for me, but with some changes.

I install angular-cli and create new project, then I follow the tutorial of the link but with this changes:

1. I create a folder called node_server
2. In run npm install express --save in root folder of my project. This add server like dependencie in your package.json without create new on node_server.
3. I create a new file in node_server called server.js, with a basic express server. This server only returns the index.html of dist folder.
4. Added the scripts to the package.json, the scripts are the same in the link tutorial, but with one change, the filename is server.js not index.js

This is my server.js file :

```js
const express = require('express');

var app = express();  
var staticRoot = __dirname;  

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));  

app.use(express.static(staticRoot));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {  
    console.log('app running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

The above comment worked pretty well for me,
just needed to make some adjustments to the scripts in package.json suggested in that link.

"build:nodeserver": "ng build && cp node-server/* dist",

"build:nodeserver-prod": "ng build -prod && cp node-server/* dist",

"serve-build" : "npm run build:nodeserver && nodemon dist/index.js",

"serve-build-prod": "npm run build:nodeserver-prod && nodemon dist/index.js"

I have a folder called node-server
which has my server.js file like above with routes for angular2 app as above,
and some api routes in there too, and some other folders in the node-server like mysql-requests and some files like config.json file

Comment: `cp node-server/* dist` is unnecessary. You need to edit the tsconfig.json file of your ng2 app and add an `outDir: 'dist'` entry. build will compile directly inside that dir. If you have a webpack config file instead, there should be an `output:{}` entry instead.

Answer (score 0):

> What I do create 2 folder on is your express server (I am using
>   Express-generator) and 1 is Angular 2 project (Angular cli )

root folder

--->server

--->ng4

---> gulpfile.js

gulp will build your app and move build files

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var deletefile = require('gulp-delete-file');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('build', function (cb) {
  exec('cd ng4/ && ng build', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    cb(err);
  });
})

gulp.task('rename', () => {
    return gulp.src("./ng4/dist/index.html")        
        .pipe(rename("ng4.html"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./server/views"));
})

gulp.task('deletefile', function () {
    var regexp = /\w*(\-\w{8}\.js){1}$|\w*(\-\w{8}\.html){1}$/;
    gulp.src(['./server/public/index.html',
            './ng4/dist/**/*.*'])
    .pipe(deletefile({reg: regexp,deleteMatch: false}));
});

gulp.task('move', function () {
    return gulp.src(["./ng4/dist/**/*.*"])       
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./server/public"));
});

gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
    runSequence('build','rename','move','deletefile',callback)    
});
```

In this way you can developed in ng4 app and run gulp command on root .

Answer (score 0):

I have this scenario; however, I want to be able to:

1. run my angular CLI project using `ng serve` instead of modifying any gulp tasks/ processes and without having to run `ng build` every time
2. have a server-side API responding on its own port independently of the frontend -- this way the microservice architecture pattern is used and concerns between frontend and backend are separated.

To accomplish this, I used [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) with the below package.json script modifications

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run-script start-frontend\" \"npm run-script start-backend\"",
    "start-frontend": "ng serve",
    "start-backend": "node index.js",
    ...
```

My backend index.js file is boilerplate but looks like this...

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ Hello: 'World' });
});

app.use('/api', router);
app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log(`API running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Now, when I want to run the app, I can type `npm start` to get everything running. Then, I can go to...

- http://localhost:3000/api/ to access the backend
- http://localhost:4200/ to access the frontend